# Optimize memory usage Android static In-App Data

Tags: java, android, memory, static, ram

[image]Thanks a lot in advance :)
I've made an Android App which is used to show some data to users, 
App is getting this data from my server as an API and I'm storing that data in Static Inner Classes which is taking up a huge amount of Memory (RAM).
What should i do to optimize what I'm trying to do, I request new data almost every minute and update it in views. Kindly suggest me something.

Comment: Could you please be more precise what kind of data you're getting from server and what are you calling "a huge amount of RAM" ?
Also, any code and/or Android Profiler screenshot is appreciated.

Comment: Hello, I'm taking about some numerical data something like stock prices. My  app is taking approx 120 MB on an Android 7.0 Device with 2 GB or RAM. I will add android profiler screenshot in my question.